# gunzip -c equivalent for tar.gz files?

Tags: tar, gunzip

What is the equivalent of gunzip -c to pipe the content of a bunch of tar.gz files without having to permanently "tar xzf" them and "tar czf" them back?

Something like:
tar xzf "-c" *.tar.gz | xargs grep something

Answer (score 3):

`O`, as in `tar xOvzf tarball files`